# php split array to string with commas

Tags: php, string, split, explode

i have an array with numbers

```
print_r($arr_usr_id[$key]);
```

output: "930933934"

now i need to convert this to 930,933,934 as a string with commas...

```
$newnumbers = (chunk_split($arr_usr_id[$key],3,","));
```

works but
output: "930,933,934," gives me a comma after the last number

with str_split($arr_usr_id[$key], 3); i get three "Array" as output...

what is the best way to sepperate the numbers (from: 123145124984 to: 123,145,124,984,...) with commas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`str_split()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) with [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$newnumbers = implode(',', str_split($arr_usr_id[$key], 3));
```

---

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$test   = '123456789';
$result = implode(',', str_split($test, 3));

var_dump($result);
?>
```

Shows:

```
string(11) "123,456,789"
```

Comment: with this i get "930933934" :/

Comment: @Jim on my side it is `string(11) "930,933,934"`. Check your syntax.

Comment: `$numbers = $arr_usr_id[$key];
var_dump($numbers);
output: string(3) "930" string(3) "933" string(3) "934"`

`$newnumbers = implode(',', str_split($numbers, 3));
var_dump($newnumbers);
output: string(3) "930" string(3) "933" string(3) "934"`

Comment: if i enter manually numbers $numbers = "465444333"; this should work...it seems to be a problem with my array your method should work

Comment: @Jim try to check database encoding and php encoding to be compatible.

Comment: Just use the `number_format` function as suggested by Alireza41. The above will not work with either negative numbers, nor numbers that do not have a length that is a multiple of 3.

Comment: @Phylogenesis , please use @ + NickName for user, you writing to. He might not get a notification in other case.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
number_format( $arr_usr_id[$key] );
```

[EDIT]

Documentation : [number_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: Documentation of which is available [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

Answer (score 2):

```
implode(',', str_split($arr_usr_id[$key], 3));
```

or

```
substr(chunk_split($arr_usr_id[$key],3,","), 0, -1);
```

Perhaps? :)